# Zonal smoothing on a specified area of a raster?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, dem, smoothing

Is there any way to smooth a specify an area on a raster, such as a DEM,  and smooth it? 
For example, I'd like to smooth out the artifact highlighted in the red box. 
What is the best course of action to remove this artifact in ArcGIS? I'm open to using another software if it's free. [image]

Comment: You could smooth a copy then through some masking etc replace the area with the data from the smoothed one but then you will have steps at the edge of the join. You could convert the DEM to points and remove the points in areas causing issues then re-build the DEM - this is the method I have used but isn't ideal